# WSO2IS with OpenID and Liferay

Tags: java, wso2, openid4java, wso2-identity-server

I followed the guide in the following link
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/WSO2+Identity+Server+as+an+OpenID+Provider
I successfully added the certificate to the cacerts of Java but after restarting Liferay I got the same error from Liferay ("You have entered invalid data. Please try again") as when there was no certificate added. Note that I didn't deviate from the guide.

I've even tried to connect with a simple openid4java application and I get the following exception:
*org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisException: 0x704: I/O transport error: peer not authenticated*
which according to most cases is because of SSL problems with the Java certificates.

Any ideas what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Problem solved...Liferay has its own JRE :-S

Answer (score 0):

you can enable openId component in Liferay portal-ext.properties as

open.id.auth.enabled=true

and then restart your tomcat server.

Hope this can help you

Comment: Thanks, good to know, but the problem was that Liferay was using it's own JRE and I had to add a certificate to the cacerts of that JRE too.

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right ,lifersay is suing their own jre but compiling some jsp page or may be some php page jdk is required,

so JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security

you can import carbon.crt whatever you generated in  CarBONicHOME/repository/resource/security

since wso2 using self sign cirtificate so you must have to available to you RUnTime JRE .

hope you understand what i mean